# NoSuchElementException while trying to read header from excel

Tags: scala, filereader, import-from-excel

I have a class that parsing an xsl file for me and mapping it by the headers of the xsl.

I have another class that is the object of each line of the xsl and is using the headers to know which cell get which attribute by the headers that im mapping before...

from some reason im getting en error NoSuchElementException on one of the headers that is actually there, and there is no typos...it worked before, I dont know whats wrong now.

this is DataSource.scala class (its a trait) that controlling the xsl:

```
import java.io.File

import com.github.tototoshi.csv.CSVReader
import jxl.{Cell, Workbook}

import scala.collection.mutable

trait DataSource {

  def read (fileName: String): Seq[Map[String, String]]
}



object CsvDataSource extends DataSource {
  import com.github.tototoshi.csv.CSVFormat
  import com.github.tototoshi.csv.Quoting
  import com.github.tototoshi.csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL

  implicit object VATBoxFormat extends CSVFormat {
    val delimiter: Char = '\t'
    val quoteChar: Char = '"'
    val escapeChar: Char = '"'
    val lineTerminator: String = "\r\n"
    val quoting: Quoting = QUOTE_MINIMAL
    val treatEmptyLineAsNil: Boolean = false
  }

  override def read(file: String): Seq[Map[String, String]] = {
    val reader = CSVReader.open(file, "UTF-16")(VATBoxFormat)
    reader.readNext()
    val country = reader.readNext().get(5)
    reader.readNext()
    reader.iteratorWithHeaders.toSeq.map(c => c + ("country" -> country))
  }
}

object ExecDataSource extends DataSource {
  override def read(file: String): Seq[Map[String, String]] = {
    val workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File(file))
    val sheet = workbook.getSheet(0)

    val rowsUsed: Int = sheet.getRows

    val headers = sheet.getRow(3).toList
    //    println(headers.map(_.getContents))
    val country = sheet.getCell(5, 1).getContents

    (4 until rowsUsed).map { i =>
      val c = headers.zip(sheet.getRow(i)).map{case (k,v) => (k.getContents, v.getContents)}.toMap
      c + ("country" -> country)
    }
  }
}
```

this is the PurchaseInfo class which is creating an object of each line of the excel:

```
case class PurchaseInfo(
                         something1: String,
                         something2: String,
                         something3: String,
                         something4: String) {
}


object PurchaseInfo {

    private def changeDateFormat(dateInString: String): String = {
    //System.out.println(dateInString)
    val formatter: SimpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy")
    val formatter2: SimpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy")
    val date: Date = formatter.parse(dateInString)
    return formatter2.format(date).toString
  }

    def fromDataSource (ds: DataSource)(fileName: String): Seq[PurchaseInfo] = {

      ds.read(fileName).map { c =>
        PurchaseInfo(
          something1 = c("Supplier Address Street Number"),
          something2 = c("Supplier Address Route"),
          something3 = c("Supplier Address Locality"),
          something4 = c("Supplier Address Postal Code")
        )
      }
    }
}
```

(iv cut some of the var's in purchaseInfo to make it shorter for the question)

Now, this is the error im getting while running my code (from a diff class that runs my actions, this is an automation project that I use selenium)

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not found: Supplier Address Street Number
    at scala.collection.MapLike$class.default(MapLike.scala:228)
    at scala.collection.AbstractMap.default(Map.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.MapLike$class.apply(MapLike.scala:141)
    at scala.collection.AbstractMap.apply(Map.scala:59)
    at PurchaseInfo$$anonfun$fromDataSource$1.apply(PurchaseInfo.scala:50)
    at PurchaseInfo$$anonfun$fromDataSource$1.apply(PurchaseInfo.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:245)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:245)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:742)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1194)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:245)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)
    at PurchaseInfo$.fromDataSource(PurchaseInfo.scala:48)
    at HolandPortal$.main(HolandPortal.scala:22)
    at HolandPortal.main(HolandPortal.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Does someone can see the issue...? I dont know why he cant find "Supplier Address Street Number", in the xsl I have this header exactly the same :/

thanks